# Store list to file for some certain time in java

Tags: java, date, text-files

I am getting a list of data from a service(data will be coming continously), this needs to be stored in a file for 1min only, after that it can be discarded.

I have tried to store the data to file and it is working, below is the sample

```
private ArrayList<Person> persons = Personservice.getPersons();

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(persons);
oos.close();
```

This is writing to the file t.tmp as expected, but i am not sure how to write to the file only for 1mins

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by resetting the file if the last modified time of that file is grater than one minute:

```
....
File file = new File("t.tmp");
if(System.currentTimeMillis() -file.lastModified() > 60000){
   // code to reset file.
} 
....
```

Answer (score 1):

> i am not sure how to write to the file only for 1mins

My interpretations is that you want to delete the file after 1 min. This can be done using a timed thread started by your current thread:

```
File file = new File("t.tmp");
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
            file.delete();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Also reference the built-in [temp file api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer task after creating the file and configured it to run for every 1 min. Once that time task is executed and file is deleted cancel the timer task.
    Sample code to execute every minute:-

```
    // Your Class
    File file = new File("t.tmp");
    Timer t1 = new Timer();
    t1.schedule(new Test(file), 0,60000);


    class Test extends TimerTask {
    File file;
    public Test (File file) {
         this.file= file;
     }
    public void run() {
    // Delete the file and cancel the task.
    file.delete();
    timer.cancel();
     }
    }
```